# Exclude specific # from scrollTo Animation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollto, hashtag

the jquery code below let me scroll to a link like #link inside my page. But now I have a three special links, #tab-1 #tab-2 #tab-3 that shall not be included in this scrollto script, just do nothing. I can't figure out how to exclude specific # from this script.

Thank you for your help!

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-80 //offset -80 for navigation height
    }, 900, 'swing');
});
```

Comment: Just add `var special = ['#tab-1', '#tab-2', '#tab-3'];` then before defining `$target` do `if( $.inArray( this.hash, special ) > -1 ){ return; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your code to this:

```
var special = ['#tab-1', '#tab-2', '#tab-3'];

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;

    if( $.inArray( target, special ) > -1 ) return;

    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-80
    }, 900, 'swing');
});
```

This defines an array of 'special' values that the hash can't equal. [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) is used to check whether the current hash matches one of the values in the `special` array. If it does then it returns and the code below isn't executed.

Another example for carousel in Bootstrap :

```
var special = ['#carousel-example-generic'];
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    if( $.inArray( target, special ) > -1 ) return;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top 
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var special = ['#tab-1', '#tab-2', '#tab-3'];

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);
    if( $.inArray( target, special ) > -1 ){
       $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-80 //offset -80 for navigation height
       }, 900, 'swing');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!
It was clearly to late yesterday for me :)
Joe's answer works great with any given #parameter I include in the var special list. So its perfect for dynamic templates too.

Thanks again!